Why doesn't some "favicon.ico" files work?
I have written a few NextJS projects and they worked fine. But recently I have encountered a strange issue.
Usually after I replace favicon.ico under /src/app directory, the icon will be updated to the latest. But recently the icon won't update and keep showing the default NextJS triangular icon. I tried to use old favicons to test, and some of them worked, some didn't. Any guru here knows why?
Favicon 1 works
Favicon 2 does not work

As this question is not related to the Ethereum anyway, I suggest you go to a normal programming Q&A site like StackOverflow to ask your questions.

Acknowledged. Will do.

Will ask in StackOverflow instead of here.
